# How to hide a div if the another one is active

Tags: angularjs

I have the current day showing as default and another date showing after selected by user,

My question is: how can I hide `TodayDate` div after the user select a date in `activeDate`.

so basically I want hide one date and show the new date selected.

**html:**

```
<div>: {{TodayDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}} </div>
<h4 class="pull-left" ng-show="activeDate">
  Active date: <span>{{activeDate}}</span>
</h4>
```

angular:

```
function link($scope, $element) {
      var $datepicker = $element.find('.date-picker').datepicker();
      $scope.TodayDate = new Date();
      $scope.activeDate = '';
      $datepicker.change(function() {
        $scope.activeDate = $(this).find('input').val();

        $scope.$apply();
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-hide="activeDate">: {{TodayDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}} </div>
<h4 class="pull-left" ng-show="activeDate">
  Active date: <span>{{activeDate}}</span>
</h4>
```

is this what you need? hide TodayDate Div when activeDate is found.

Answer (score 1):

Html,

```
<div ng-hide="date">: {{TodayDate | date:"dd-MM-yyyy"}} </div>
<h4 class="pull-left" ng-show="date">
  Active date: <span>{{activeDate}}</span>
</h4>
```

Angular code,

```
function link($scope, $element) {
      var $datepicker = $element.find('.date-picker').datepicker();
      $scope.TodayDate = new Date();
      $scope.activeDate = '';
      $scope.date = false;
      $datepicker.change(function() {
        $scope.activeDate = $(this).find('input').val();
        $scope.date = true;
        // Because the datepicker change happens outside of the Angular digest,
        // we need to call the apply method
        $scope.$apply();
      });
    }
```

Added a variable `$scope.data` to manage show and hide.